# How to create database handler for KDB using Ruby DBI?

Tags: ruby, database, kdb

I'm trying to connect to KDB through my application which currently using DBI(ruby) and the Oracle handler ( OCI8).

I searched for an existing implementation of a KDB handler but could not find one. Now I'm trying to implement it, but have found no documentation on it and don't know where to start.

Can someone point to some work on creating such a thing and the possible estimation on the effort?

Answer (score 2):

There is very little documentation, as you've already discovered. Try JRuby in between, or implement your own IPC handler - the protocol is straightforward:

https://code.kx.com/q/ref/ipc/

Comment: Thanks for the link, I'm implementing my own IPC handler, but in ruby there's no handy way to manipulate byte arrays, like the python array module. Do you know of any?

Comment: My knowledge of Ruby is really poor. But if you could call Java for example from Ruby then just use the appropriate language API from Kx to do the (de)serialisation and get the result as a (java) object.